# Email subject = string subject = "test {0}", test2; Outputs:"test {0}"

Tags: c#, string, email, variables, subject

I am creating a program that sends an email with some data the program collected from the user beforehand.

Currently, my problem is that when i use:

```
string subject = "test {0}", test2;
```

The email I receive is this output:

> test {0}

and not the expected output of:

> "test test2".

Is there something I am missing?

I just tested something else out, by removing the text and only using the variable as a subject, worked fine. But why isnt the text/string + variable working?

Vs says that the variable I am adding, `test2`, is already defined.

Full code:

```
string test2 = "test";
string subject = "test {0}", test2;
string body = "test1";
```

Comment: You need to tell what programming language you're using, and show a [mcve].

Comment: Language added, c#, i forgot cause i changed my title, sorry for the inconvenience. <3

Comment: Yes will do, thanks a bunch <3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you need to wrap the formatted string in the String.Format() or a Console.WriteLine();

It should be

```
string test2 = "test";
string subject = String.Format("test {0}", test2);
string body = "test1";
```

Without the String.Format C# just thinks that you're defining 2 separate string variables. It creates 1 variable named subject which is equal to "test {0}" and another variable named test2 which you already defined in the line before which is why it's complaining.
It thinks you're trying to say

```
string test2 = "test";
string subject = "test {0}";
string test2;
string body = "test1";
```

Read the documentation for composite formatting.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting

Comment: Right, thanks, that worked out. That is so great, ty <3